# unexpected non-void return value in void function

Tags: swift, closures

Below is my code. I'm learning closures. I'm getting an error that my function would not return a value. Can someone help?

```
func operationOnNumbers(_ a: Int, _ b: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int) {
    let result = operation(a, b)
    print(result)
    return result
}

let addClosure = {(a: Int, b: Int) in
    a + b
}

operationOnNumbers(5, 7, operation: addClosure)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. You're returning "result" but your function signature doesn't have a return type.  Remove the "return result"  line

Comment: @AlainT. Thanks, yeah the error is very explicit. Got it, thanks for your help. I can just add the return type as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this modified code as you have missed return type in the function ( -> Int)

```
func operationOnNumbers(_ a: Int, _ b: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int{

    let result = operation(a, b)
    print(result)
    return result
}

let addClosure = {(a: Int, b: Int) in
    a + b
}

operationOnNumbers(5, 7, operation: addClosure)
```

Comment: But now you get a warning about ignoring the return value on the call to `operationOnNumbers`.

Comment: @Henrikaly Anibal, You can use variable to store the return value.